# GeoServer: Rasters in GE and opacity with map-type:values and css

Tags: raster, geoserver, kml

I am pretty new to GeoServer and am having some issues with styling rasters for Google Earth using the css plugin.

I have a raster that covers a particular areas which has 1 band and 6 values in that band. I have  the following css style code

```
/* @title raster */
* {
raster-channels: auto;
raster-opacity: 0.4;
raster-color-map-type: values;
raster-color-map:
 color-map-entry(#00FF00, 0) color-map-entry(#008000, 1) color-map-entry(#00FFFF, 2) color-map-entry(#0000FF, 3)  color-map-entry(#FF8200, 4) color-map-entry(#FF0000, 5);  
}
```

On the preview I am getting the expected results (everything the right color and opacity according to plan). When I download the KML but with Google Earth I am seeing the raster with no opacity and surrounding the raster is black which covers the whole globe.

I have also found when i leave out the 'raster-color-map-type' property, it looks like I want it to, but I need discrete vales rather that ranges

Has anyone else seen this issue before, and do you have a way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that Google Earth has troubles with the paletted PNG GeoServer generates when using a discrete colormap (as opposed to using a color ramp, which generated 32 bit full color PNGs. 
However I don't think there is a way to force GeoServer to generate PNG 24 bits in that case.

Maybe you can try the interpolation approach to deliver solid colors anyways like this (ugly, but may work):

`raster-color-map:
 color-map-entry(#00FF00, 0) 
 color-map-entry(#00FF00, 1) 
 color-map-entry(#008000, 1) 
 color-map-entry(#008000, 2) 
 color-map-entry(#00FFFF, 2) 
 color-map-entry(#00FFFF, 3) 
 color-map-entry(#0000FF, 3)
 color-map-entry(#0000FF, 4)
 color-map-entry(#FF8200, 4)
 color-map-entry(#FF8200, 5) 
 color-map-entry(#FF0000, 5);`